# How to scroll across fragments with TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am trying to make my app scrollable via sliding from left to right on the tab page. Right now the app has the ability to scroll across tabs by scrolling the tab bar, but I don't know how to implement a scroll for the entire app.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static MainActivity instance;

    private FragmentOne fragmentOne;
    private FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;
    private TabLayout allTabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instance=this;

        getAllWidgets();
        bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
        setupTabLayout();
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private void getAllWidgets() {
        allTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }

    private void setupTabLayout() {
        fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
        fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();

        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("ONE"),true);
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("TWO"));
    }

    private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent()
    {
        allTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition)
    {
        switch (tabPosition)
        {
            case 0 :
                replaceFragment(fragmentOne);
                break;
            case 1 :
                replaceFragment(fragmentTwo);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFFF"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFF"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make your question clear so that you can be helped!!.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code I have for the TabLayout:

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Main activity:

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment(), "People");
    adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment(), "Group");
    adapter.addFragment(new PeopleFragment(), "Calls");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```